# Windows 8 preloader (loading icon) using HTML5 and javascript without images

Tags: javascript, css, html

I noticed a simple thing while looking at the screen of Windows 8 loading screen, there is a preloader (or loading icon) which is quite interesting, it has a bit of gravity/swing effect. I wanted to replicate the same using javascript and css but I don't have much understanding of javascript animations, thus wanted to know if you can give me a direction to head, where I can find similar kind of example. You could also help by providing a snippet of code which has similar kind of animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked this one http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sonic-looping-loaders/

Comment: Still now I could find these two where you can start with: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sonic-looping-loaders/ http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/

Comment: thanks @coder , I will go through this and will try to implement gravity effect too...

Comment: Friends, if you could come up with exact solution to the problem (creating windows 8 metro style preloader), please do share ... :)

Comment: This one uses CSS3 http://codepen.io/janrubio/pen/5/2

Comment: @jrubio Awesome man! ... let's work on the cross browser implementation of the same.

Comment: Check my answer! I update it... Now you can create preloader using only CSS with easy tool :)

Comment: pure CSS example answer below

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check website [CSSload](http://cssload.net/). Here you can make your CSS loader in few seconds. I've made Windows 8 loader, so you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/nPQNH/).

```
@keyframes orbit {
   0% {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index:99;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   }

   7% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotate(300deg);
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      origin:0%;
   }

   30% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform:rotate(410deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      origin:7%;
   }

   39% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotate(645deg);
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      origin:30%;
   }

   70% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotate(770deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      origin:39%;
   }

   75% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotate(900deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      origin:70%;
   }

   76% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform:rotate(900deg);
   }

   100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(900deg);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, try [this code example](http://codepen.io/janrubio/pen/DusIE)...

Comment: Animated GIFs can stall in single-threaded Javascript environments during script execution that involves DOM manipulation so hardware enabled CSS3 animations perform much better in my opinion. I updated your JSFiddle to eliminate extraneous cssload.net generated markup by removing the child wInnerBall class divs and instead rendering them with :after pseudo-element CSS and removing the wBall ids and styling them by nth-child selectors a la Jan Rubio's codepen example. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nPQNH/48/)

Comment: Also CSS animations are not plagued with ugly matte colors like 8-bit transparent GIFs.

Comment: @TaeKwonJoe, you're right! But I have problem with corrected example you shared. There is only one animated dot. I can't see the others. Thanks for sharing the better solution! :)

Comment: @Vukašin what browser were you using in which only one dot is displayed? I just double-checked with Firefox 12.0, Chrome 28.0.1500.52 and IE 10.0.9200.16599 and all 5 dots rendered properly.
[http://jsfiddle.net/nPQNH/48/](http://jsfiddle.net/nPQNH/48/)

Comment: If we use it on a commercial website, won't it lead to copyright infringement? Won't Microsoft have any problem with their work being copied by a commercial website?

Answer (score 9):

Here is my pure CSS3 implementation with no Javascript in which I combined [CSSload](http://cssload.net/) and [Jan Rubio's codepen](http://codepen.io/janrubio/pen/DusIE) techniques for minimal markup and no id selectors:

***HTML:***

```
<div class="loader">
   <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.loader { position: relative; width: 64px; height: 64px; }
.loader .circle { position: absolute; width: 61px; height: 61px; opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(225deg); -moz-animation: orbit 7.15s infinite; -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg); -webkit-animation: orbit 7.15s infinite; -ms-transform: rotate(225deg); -ms-animation: orbit 7.15s infinite; -o-transform: rotate(225deg); -o-animation: orbit 7.15s infinite; transform: rotate(225deg); animation: orbit 7.15s infinite; }
.loader .circle:after { content:''; position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 8px; background: #04C5DE; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -ms-border-radius: 8px; -o-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
.loader .circle:nth-child(1) { -moz-animation-delay: 1.56s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1.56s; -ms-animation-delay: 1.56s; -o-animation-delay: 1.56s; animation-delay: 1.56s; }
.loader .circle:nth-child(2) { -moz-animation-delay: 0.31s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.31s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.31s; -o-animation-delay: 0.31s; animation-delay: 0.31s; }
.loader .circle:nth-child(3) { -moz-animation-delay: 0.62s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.62s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.62s; -o-animation-delay: 0.62s; animation-delay: 0.62s; }
.loader .circle:nth-child(4) { -moz-animation-delay: 0.94s; -webkit-animation-delay: 0.94s; -ms-animation-delay: 0.94s; -o-animation-delay: 0.94s; animation-delay: 0.94s; }
.loader .circle:nth-child(5) { -moz-animation-delay: 1.25s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s; -ms-animation-delay: 1.25s; -o-animation-delay: 1.25s; animation-delay: 1.25s; }

@-moz-keyframes orbit {
    0% { opacity: 1; z-index: 99; -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    7% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: rotate(300deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; -moz-origin: 0%; }
    30% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: rotate(410deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; -moz-origin: 7%; }
    39% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: rotate(645deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; -moz-origin: 30%; }
    70% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: rotate(770deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -moz-origin: 39%; }
    75% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: rotate(900deg); -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -moz-origin: 70%; }
    76% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(900deg); }
    100% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotate(900deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
    0% { opacity: 1; z-index: 99; -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    7% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; -webkit-origin: 0%; }
    30% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotate(410deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; -webkit-origin: 7%; }
    39% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotate(645deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; -webkit-origin: 30%; }
    70% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotate(770deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -webkit-origin: 39%; }
    75% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -webkit-origin: 70%; }
    76% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg); }
    100% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotate(900deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes orbit {
    0% { opacity: 1; z-index: 99; -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    7% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: rotate(300deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; -ms-origin: 0%; }
    30% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: rotate(410deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; -ms-origin: 7%; }
    39% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: rotate(645deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; -ms-origin: 30%; }
    70% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: rotate(770deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -ms-origin: 39%; }
    75% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: rotate(900deg); -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -ms-origin: 70%; }
    76% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(900deg); }
    100% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotate(900deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes orbit {
    0% { opacity: 1; z-index: 99; -o-transform: rotate(180deg); -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    7% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: rotate(300deg); -o-animation-timing-function: linear; -o-origin: 0%; }
    30% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: rotate(410deg); -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; -o-origin: 7%; }
    39% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: rotate(645deg); -o-animation-timing-function: linear; -o-origin: 30%; }
    70% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: rotate(770deg); -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -o-origin: 39%; }
    75% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: rotate(900deg); -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; -o-origin: 70%; }
    76% { opacity: 0; -o-transform: rotate(900deg); }
    100% { opacity: 0; -o-transform: rotate(900deg); }
}

@keyframes orbit {
    0% { opacity: 1; z-index: 99; transform: rotate(180deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    7% { opacity: 1; transform: rotate(300deg); animation-timing-function: linear; origin: 0%; }
    30% { opacity: 1; transform: rotate(410deg); animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; origin: 7%; }
    39% { opacity: 1; transform: rotate(645deg); animation-timing-function: linear; origin: 30%; }
    70% { opacity: 1; transform: rotate(770deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; origin: 39%; }
    75% { opacity: 1; transform: rotate(900deg); animation-timing-function: ease-out; origin: 70%; }
    76% { opacity: 0; transform: rotate(900deg); }
    100% { opacity: 0; transform: rotate(900deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure, but maybe that's what you want:

```
<progress style="color: white;" class="win-medium win-ring"></progress>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is another take on the Modern UI ProgressRing animation in CSS3. It is based on the already mentioned Jan Rubio's [solution](http://codepen.io/janrubio/details/DusIE) with some tweaks (still needs tweaking, though).

Watch [the live example](http://codepen.io/Chudesnov/pen/gDhGw) or use the following code if the codepen is unavailable:

***HTML***

```
<div class='progress-ring'>
  <div class='progress-ring__wrap'>
    <div class='progress-ring__circle'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='progress-ring__wrap'>
    <div class='progress-ring__circle'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='progress-ring__wrap'>
    <div class='progress-ring__circle'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='progress-ring__wrap'>
    <div class='progress-ring__circle'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='progress-ring__wrap'>
    <div class='progress-ring__circle'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***CSS (LESS, unprefixed)***

```
body {background:#111}
@t:4000ms;
@d:40px;
@color:#ffffff;
.progress-ring {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: @d/5;
  width: @d;
  height: @d;
  margin: auto;

  .progress-ring__wrap {
    position: absolute;
      width: @d - 2;
      height: @d - 2;

    .progress-ring__circle {
      transform: rotate(225deg);
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-name: orbit;
      animation-duration: @t;
      width: @d - 2;
      height: @d - 2;

      opacity: 0;

      &:after {
      content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: @d/8;
        height: @d/8;
        border-radius: @d/8;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5% @color;
        background: @color; /* Pick a color */
      }
    }


    @r:-14deg;
    @m:30;
    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform:rotate(@r);
      .progress-ring__circle {  animation-delay: @t/@m; }
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform:rotate(@r*2);
      .progress-ring__circle {  animation-delay: @t/@m*2; }
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      transform:rotate(@r*3);
      .progress-ring__circle {  animation-delay: @t/@m*3; }
    }
    &:nth-child(5) {
      transform:rotate(@r*4);
      .progress-ring__circle {  animation-delay: @t/@m*4; }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes orbit { 
  0%   { transform:rotate(225deg); opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; } 

  7%   { transform:rotate(345deg);
         animation-timing-function: linear; }

  35%   { transform:rotate(495deg);
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; }

  42%   { transform:rotate(690deg);
          animation-timing-function: linear; }

  70%   { transform:rotate(835deg); opacity: 1; 
         animation-timing-function: linear; }

  76% {opacity: 1;}

  77%   { transform:rotate(955deg);
         animation-timing-function: ease-in; }

  78% { transform:rotate(955deg); opacity: 0; }
  100% { transform:rotate(955deg); opacity: 0; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure about javascript, but you can download it from http://preloaders.net/en/search/windows8

Answer (score 1):

I discovered you could find a similar script on `C:\Windows\WinStore\WinStore.css` and `WinStore.htm`, Just open `Winstore.htm` and you will discover a similar ring loading animation, provided by `IE10`, if only someone could dump the animation info from Windows Shell... If you see with Notepad the `WinStore.css` you will see something like this:

```
splashProgress::-ms-fill
{
    animation-name: **-ms-ring**;
}
```

Is that variable an animation info stored somewhere in the Windows Shell???

I tested loading the HTML page in Chrome and Firefox, nothing, just a normal loading bar.

Sorry for my bad english. I'm from Argentina.

Comment: Some of the Styles process on Metro such as `-ms-ring` and `html:-ms-lang(ar, dv, fa, he, ku-Arab, pa-Arab, prs, ps, sd-Arab, syr, ug, ur, qps-plocm)`. They are just for windows and windows process them!